# No such module 'Amplify' & Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature")

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to compile an Xcode project. I'm getting 2 runtime errors:

```
No such module 'Amplify'
```

&

```
/Users/????????/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/screener_app-gkvpndyzdgqrsreqyokgisatdzav/Build/Intermediates.noindex/screener_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/screener_app.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AuthButtonView.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'screener_app' from project 'screener_app') Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
```

The screenshot is seen below.

I have tried a handful of things:

- cleaned build folder
- install/update pods
- removed derived data

I'm not sure what to do from here. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: I am seeing that the workspace is compiling but the project folder is not.

[image: screenshot of build error]

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am trying to run my project in a new computer. The project runs fine in xcode 13.1 (OS : Big Sur). Trying to run on xcode 13.4.1 (Monetery) and I keep getting the same error that you are getting.

Comment: I posted on Apple Developer and got this response. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707305 Still figuring out how to solve though.